# Is there a way to monitor what data is displayed on iPad/iPhone

Tags: monitoring, ipad

My company has an iPad/iPhone app which shows news, blogs, videos and various articles. This data is obtained from a rss feed. Additionally it also shows a lot of stock market data. My question is, is there a way to check if my application is displaying the information which matches exactly with the rss feed data?

The only way i can think of doing it, is to monitor all http calls going out from my iPad and garbing the response using tools such as Wireshark or charles, and then subsequently compare the http response with the rss feed. But this approach still does not handle the scenario "what exactly is being displayed to the end user situations"?

If i use the http monitoring approach, how would i go about comparing results on charles or Wireshark.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than wireshark, try using a http proxy, like fiddler2.  Then save the Rss content to a file, and load it into a browser, like firefox.  Then you'll have to visually diff the two views of the RSS feed.